# jquery dialog does not open second when loading content from another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery UI dialog which loads content from another page.
The dialog opens the first time, but not a second time. If don't load anything into the dialog it works the second time too.

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94jgT/). [It works, the error must be somewhere else]

HTML:

```
<a class="click" href="form.php">form</a>
<a class="click" href="data.php">data</a>
<a class="click" href="user.php">user</a>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true
    });

    $('.click').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog').load(this.href);
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the dialog in the load's complete callback - the load will run async by default, and so it likely won't be complete by the time you hit the open - that might be what's messing it up (though it's hard to say when the example works :-) )

```
var $dialog;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: true
  });

  $('.click').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $dialog.load(this.href, function() {
     $dialog.dialog('open');
    });
  });
});​
```